# Django templates ; Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, html, django

I have this error with templates, I don't understand what's the problem, pls help

> NoReverseMatch at /login/
> Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://localhost:5000/login/
> Django Version: 3.1
> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
> Exception Value:
> Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
> Exception Location: /home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
> Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
> Python Version: 3.8.5
> Python Path:
> ['/home/daniiar/land-gPage',
> '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
> '/usr/lib/python3.8',
> '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
> '/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
> '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
> Server time:    Sat, 16 Jan 2021 13:39:04 +0600
> Error during template rendering
> In template /home/daniiar/land-gPage/auto/templates/base.html, error at line 14
> Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

**FULL TRACEBACK**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 202, in _get_response
> response = response.render()
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
> self.content = self.rendered_content
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
> return template.render(context, self._request)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
> return self.template.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
> return self._render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
> return compiled_parent._render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
> result = block.nodelist.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
> return nodelist.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
> url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
> return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
> File "/home/daniiar/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
> raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <span class="logo">Bookmarks</span>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <ul class="menu">
        <li {% if section == 'dashboard' %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
          <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">My dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li {% if section == 'images' %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
          <a href="#">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li {% if section == 'people' %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
          <a href="#">People</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="user">
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        Hello {{ request.user }},
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log-in</a>
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  </div>
  {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
      {% for message in messages %}
        <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
          {{ message|safe }}
            <a href="#" class="close">x</a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Log-in</h1>
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p>
      Your username and password didn't match.
      Please try again.
    </p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in. If you don't have an account <a href="{% url '' %}">register here</a></p>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="login-form">
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
      <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
    <p><a href="{% url '' %}">Forgotten your  password?</a></p>
  </div>
<!--  <div class="social">-->
<!--    <ul>-->
<!--      <li class="facebook"><a href="{% url "social:begin" "facebook" %}">Sign in with Facebook</a></li>-->
<!--      <li class="twitter"><a href="{% url "social:begin" "twitter" %}">Login with Twitter</a></li>-->
<!--      <li class="google"><a href="{% url "social:begin" "google-oauth2" %}">Login with Google</a></li>-->
<!--    </ul>-->
<!--  </div>-->
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import *
from .models import *
from django.views import View
from .forms import FeedbackForm


def formuser(request):
    return render(request, 'account/testregister.html')

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request, username=cd['username'],password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated '\
                                        'successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'auto/login.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request,
                  'auto/dashboard.html',
                  {'section': 'dashboard'})


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(
                user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return render(request,
                          'auto/register_done.html',
                          {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,
                  'auto/register.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form})


@login_required
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your profile')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request,
                  'auto/edit.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'profile_form': profile_form})


@login_required
def editPartner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,data=request.POST)
        partner_form = PartnerEditForm(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and partner_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            partner_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your profile')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        partner_form = PartnerEditForm(instance=request.user.partner)
    return render(request,
                  'auto/edit.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'partner_form': partner_form})




class FeedbackView(View):
    
    def post(self, request):
        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            phoneNumber = form.cleaned_data['phoneNumber']
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            subject = 'Новое сообщение'
            message = 'Новая заявка!' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' + 'Номер телефона: ' + phoneNUmber + '\r\n' + '\r\n' + 'ФИО:' + name + '\r\n' + 'Сообщение' + text
            bot.send_message(628980737, message)
        return redirect('home')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views


urlpatterns = [

    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('formregister/', views.formuser, name="formuser"),
    # change password urls
    # path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    # path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
    # reset password urls
    # path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    # path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    # path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    # path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),


   
]
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Can you add the full traceback and the view that handles `/login/` to your question? It's not obvious that it's an issue with your template

Comment: okk, one minute

Comment: You're passing an empty string to your `register here` link url tag in `login.html`. You should be passing a valid url path name

Comment: No, it doesn't help, I tried

Comment: What doesn't help? The correct path name seems to be "register", have you tried `<a href="{% url 'register' %}">register here</a>`?

Comment: yes, have tried that

Comment: You have the same issue for your "Forgotten your password" link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this error is the following line in your `login.html`:

```
<p>Please, use the following form to log-in. If you don't have an account
<a href="{% url '' %}">register here</a></p>
```

By calling the `url` template tag with an empty argument, you will naturally get the error `Reverse for '' not found.` The solution is to specify the url name:

```
<p>Please, use the following form to log-in. If you don't have an account
<a href="{% url 'register' %}">register here</a></p>
```

Probably just an oversight on your part, happens to me all the time :-)